# Run windows form before project installation

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-deployment

I want to run a windows form before the setup wizard for my project installation starts.

I can use a custom action and specify the windows form at the install stage.

But it runs after 2/3's of the wizard steps have been completed and installation continues.

I want to run my form first and then project installation starts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a couple of choices here, depending on the setup program that you are using:

1) Execute an application containing your form as a prerequisite. This should work for most installers.

2) If you are using a third party application such as Installshield, you could recreate the form in that application and integrate it into the UI of the installation so that it appears where needed.

3) Some third-party installers, such as Installshield, allow you to execute .Net code at specific junctures in the application, so you could utilize this functionality.

(I am NOT pushing Installshield, it's just the only third-party installer that I have worked with)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio setup project then this is the problem with it. Custom actions are executed in the last stage of the wizard ( Note - Before any files are copied to your system). You cannot get the expected behavior you want with this type of installer.

Note : If windows form that you want to launch does some kind of pre-req check, then that is possible with MSI installers. This will happen at the first stage of the wizard. That can be achieved using Launch conditions.

Hope this answers your question.